# Aligning shapes to terrain in CityEngine?

Tags: shapefile, terrain, cityengine

I have a problem. As soon as I click "Align shapes to Terrain", my shapefile rectifies and falls down the edge.

In the first picture(Border_Issue1) you can see that all shapefiles have the right size, in the second picture(Border_Issue) you can see the mentioned problem.

Does anyone have the same problem and can help me?

[image]

[image]

Comment: From what I see in the image I assume that your shape is just barely outside the terrain area.
Since CityEngine sees that this point is outside the terrain (even if only just) it falls back to y=0.
Could you try to move the shape vertices towards the terrain a little and try again?

Answer (score 0):

I found my mistake. The shapefiles were polygons and after I converted them into multipatches everything works fine again.

I don't know if this is the general solution now, but in my case it works fine.

Thanks for your replies and help